# How can I evaluate ${\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(\pi + h) + 1}{h}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm supposed to evaluate the following limit using the cosine of a sum and one of the "special limits" which are ${\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1}$ and ${\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}=0}$.

The limit is : ${\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(\pi + h) + 1}{h}}$

I currently have : ${\frac{\cos(\pi)\cos(h) - \sin(\pi)\sin(h) + 1}{h}}$

I'm not sure where to go from here and have been stuck for awhile, help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $\cos(\pi+x) = -\cos(x)$

Comment: Would you mind telling me where you got that from?

Comment: Its a property of $\cos(x)$, look at a graph of $\cos(x)$ put one finger at a small $x$ and the other at the same distance after $\pi$, see that one is the negative of the other as you track it. That's not a formal proof but a good way to remember it and find other relations

Comment: cool thank you!

Comment: If you have studied derivatives already, derivatives of trigonometric functions in articular, you would see that your limit is the derivative of $\cos$ at $\pi$: $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\pi+h)-\cos(\pi)}{h}=\cos'(\pi)=-\sin(\pi)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written it correctly. Now because ${\sin(\pi)=0}$ and ${\cos(\pi)=-1}$ it simplifies further to

$${\frac{\cos(\pi)\cos(h) - \sin(\pi)\sin(h) + 1}{h}=\frac{-1\times \cos(h) - 0\times \sin(h)+1}{h}=\frac{-\cos(h) + 1}{h}}$$

can you take it from here?

Comment: The fact that $\cos(\pi+h) = -\cos(h)$ is a much simpler identity than the general identity that says $\cos(g+h) = \cos g\cos h - \sin g\sin h,$ since it just says the part of the cosine function that's half a period over from the part that's above the axis looks the same as the part above the axis except it's turned upside-down. $\qquad $

Comment: @MichaelHardy right, but OP gave his attempt, and I showed him how to continue. It maybe simpler, but there was nothing wrong with OPs attempt, so I addressed it

Comment: this is what I was looking for, needed to combine both identities. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DCdaKING no problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Since $\cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(\pi) =0$ we have:
$$\frac{\cos(\pi)\cos(h) - \sin(\pi)\sin(h)+1}{h} = \frac{-\cos(h)+1}{h} = \frac{1-\cos(h)}{h}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is actually asking you the derivative of $\cos(x)$ at $x=\pi$.

We can rewrite the expression as:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\pi+h)-\cos(\pi)}{\pi+h-\pi}\longrightarrow \cos^\prime(\pi)$$
The derivative of $f(x)$ refers to $\lim_{h\longrightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{x+h-x}$

If you know derivative, you know that $\cos^\prime(\pi)=-\sin(\pi)=0$

I am not sure if this problem is designed to be solved this way, but it reminds me a problem I did before, and that problem is solved this way.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The hint was given to you:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos(\pi+h)+1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos\pi\cos h-\sin\pi\sin h+1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-\cos h}h=0.$$